# Chrome file upload not recognising accept mimetype 'text/csv'

Tags: google-chrome, csv, mime-types

I'm trying to limit the files shown in the pop-up file selector when using chrome to just csv files (I would settle for just text files including csvs).

I have tried the following `accept` options:

- `text/csv`; All files shown
- `text/comma-separated-values`; All files shown
- `application/csv`; All files shown
- `application/excel`; All files shown
- `application/vnd.ms-excel`; 97-03 Excel workbooks, but no csvs
- `text/*`; Some text files shown, but no csvs
- `application/*`; Some application files shown, but no csvs

Am I missing something?

Comment: Is there an answer to this already? I'm experiencing the same problem.

Comment: I was able to have it work with `<input type="file" accept="text/csv">`. Running Chrome 50.0.2661.94 on OS X El Capitan 10.11.2

Comment: @BrandonAnzaldi I am also having success with "text/csv" now on mac.. will have to verify on windows!

Comment: This works on OSX but still not working on Windows.  Chrome reports an invalid mimetype.  I'm still looking for a solution to this

Answer (score 5):

The solution is simple, although not very intuitive given the other mime types.

Just use `.csv` and Chrome will filter your files properly.